# Which one of the following PHP array structure would be using less memory?

Tags: php, arrays, php-internals

Which one of the following would be using less memory?

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[1] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$myArray[2] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$myArray[3] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

or

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[1] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[2] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[3] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[4] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[5] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[6] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[7] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[8] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[9] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[10] = array(1,2,3);
```

`array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` and `array(1,2,3)` may not repeat in the real scenario.

Will there be a performance gain if I use one over other in terms of CPU and memory utilization.

Comment: `memory_get_usage()`

Comment: Theoretically, memory utilisation should be the same. For cpu, it depends always depends on the operation you want to do.

Comment: @Upsilon42 - in the second case, if I have more keys, will the bucket size of the hash table affect the memory utilised?

Answer (score 8):

In the first case you're making 4 arrays with a total of 33 elements. In the second case you're making 11 arrays with a total of 40 elements.

Each array has its own overhead, and each element also has its own overhead. So the second case has more memory usage because it has both more arrays and more elements.

Let's test it.

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2016 10:40:26) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Test script 1:

```
<?php
$myArray = array();
$myArray[1] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$myArray[2] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$myArray[3] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
echo "4 arrays, 33 elements: ", memory_get_usage(), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
4 arrays, 33 elements: 354448
```

Test script 2:

```
<?php
$myArray = array();
$myArray[1] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[2] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[3] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[4] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[5] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[6] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[7] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[8] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[9] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[10] = array(1,2,3);
echo "11 arrays, 40 elements: ", memory_get_usage();
```

Output:

```
11 arrays, 40 elements: 358720
```

So indeed, the second case consumes more memory.

That said, this test is misleading. The second script is longer and so when compiled will result in more instructions, so it will take up more space even before it is executed. At least in PHP 7, we can't measure how much space the sub-arrays (`array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` and `array(1,2,3)`) take up, because in this case they are not actually created when you assign them to `$myArray`, but rather when the script is compiled. So even if we compare memory usage at the start and end of the script, we won't learn how big they were. Plus, all those arrays have identical content, so PHP may have deduplicated them so that there's only one `array(1,2,3)`, not three.

Anyway, these are so small that it is not worth worrying about memory consumption. It is often said that "premature optimisation is the root of all evil". Worrying about precisely how many bytes your PHP arrays take up when you're not dealing with very much data is pointless. And if it's going to make your code harder to read and maintain without an actual need, don't change it.

Comment: Sorry for interruption but searching for php internals I found your post and wanna say there's an error here. In first test case we have 3 elements containing 10 child elements each + [0], which equals to 31 total array elements. In the second case we have 10 elements containing 3 child elements + [0], which should be equal to also to 31 total array elements, not 40

Comment: @1000Gbps There's no 0th array element. And in the second case, each sub-array is an array element itself, so you have 10 subarrays plus 10*3 elements of subarrays, so 40 elements. I did make a mistake in the first one, though: there's 33 elements, not 31, I'm not sure where I got that number from.

Comment: Ok, you're right about the existence of [0], but why https://3v4l.org/MR1EL gives 30 for the second case?

Comment: 5min edit rule ... Why we must count sub arrays as main array elements when we're already counting sub array values and prove they exist?

Comment: @1000Gbps I didn't say anything about counting them as as “main” array elements. Anyway, the reason I count them is because every array element costs memory.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** the second takes up more memory.

---

While @Andrea's answer is is great, I figured I'd provide just a little more insight into the internals aspect of calculating PHP memory accurately. Because `memory_get_usage()` doesn't accurately represent the amount of memory a particular data structure in PHP is consuming, but rather the general heap size of the PHP VM, it's hard to look at that way.

I wrote a crude PHP extension extension, called [Array Analysis PHP](https://github.com/srgoogleguy/Array-Analysis-PHP), a long time ago that allows you inspect the internal memory of a PHP array for this reason.

> **WARNING** this extension probably won't compile on PHP 7, but here are the results you get in PHP 5.

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[1] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$myArray[2] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$myArray[3] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

var_dump(array_size($myArray)); // int(4312)

$myArray = array();
$myArray[1] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[2] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[3] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[4] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[5] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[6] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[7] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[8] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[9] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[10] = array(1,2,3);

var_dump(array_size($myArray)); // int(6272)
```

These values may or may not differ slightly on your system due to padding, but it's a fairly accurate representation of the of the array size and one far less ambiguous than what you might see from `memory_get_usage()`, since this extension explicitly digs into the internal structure that makes up the array in PHP's memory, and inspects it piece-by-piece to figure out its size.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 154432

$myArray = array();
$myArray[1] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[2] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[3] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[4] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[5] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[6] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[7] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[8] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[9] = array(1,2,3);
$myArray[10] = array(1,2,3);

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 157360
```